# The positive semi-definiteness of the element-wise matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I understand that if two matrices are PSD, then the element-wise product of the two matrices is also PSD.
However if a matrix in the form $K = A \odot B$ is PSD for **any** PSD matrix $A$. How about $B$? Must it be PSD? How to prove it?

I am thinking about the following proof.

Since $ A \odot B$ is PSD, we have:

for any column real vector $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{x}^T(A \odot B)\mathbf{x} \geq 0$.

That is, trace($\mathbf{x}^T(A \odot B)\mathbf{x} $)$\geq 0$ $\implies$ trace($A*diag(\mathbf{x}^T)*B*diag(\mathbf{x}) $)$\geq 0$.

As A is PSD, we decompose it as $A = LL^T$. Then we have:

trace($L^T*diag(\mathbf{x}^T)*B*diag(\mathbf{x})*L $)$\geq 0$.

Then, for any column real vector $\mathbf{y}$,

$\mathbf{y}^T*$trace($L^T*diag(\mathbf{x}^T)*B*diag(\mathbf{x})*L $)$*\mathbf{y}$$\geq 0$.

$\implies$ $\mathbf{y}^T*L^T*diag(\mathbf{x}^T)*B*diag(\mathbf{x})*L*\mathbf{y} \geq 0$.

If we can show $\mathbf{y}^T*L^T*diag(\mathbf{x}^T)$ can represent any real vector, then we can prove $B$ is PSD.

The problem is how to prove $\mathbf{y}^T*L^T*diag(\mathbf{x}^T)$ can represent any real vector.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a matrix such that for any positive semidefinite $B$ the matrix $A\odot B$ is positive semidefinite.

Consider matrix
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&\dots&1\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1&\dots&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
It's positive semidefinite, so $A\odot B$ is positive semidefinite. On the other hand, $A\odot B=A$. Hence $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to theoretically prove it?

Comment: I rephrased the answer to look like a proof.

Comment: Thanks! I am also thinking about the following proof: A⊙B is PSD, then for any x, we have x'(A⊙B )x >= 0. By applying bi-linear form, we have  x'(A⊙B )x = trace(A*diag(x')*B*diag(x)) >=0. Since A is PSD, we can decompose it: A = LL'; Then we obtain: trace(L'*diag(x')*B*diag(x)*L)>=0. For any y, we have: y' trace(L'*diag(x')*B*diag(x)*L)y >= 0. i,e. y'*L'*diag(x')*B*diag(x)*L*y>=0. If y'*L'*diag(x') can represent any real vector, then B is PSD.

Comment: Notice that trace is a number, so you can't really multiply it by y' and y unless y is a number as well. But then it doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: y is a vector and trace is scalar, they can't multiply?

Comment: They can (sorry, my wording isn't perfect). But why do you multiply them? If a scalar is positive, multiplying it by y' and y is superfluous.

Comment: To construct a form of y'*B*y >=0, if this holds for any real vector y, then B must be PSD

Comment: It makes sense if B is a matrix, but trace(...) is a scalar. And by the way, y' trace(M)y is not the same as y'My (even signs of them may differ)